# SQL Query to sum fields from multiple different tables

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, sum

I'm trying to combine 2 queries to obtain single data. but the value not correct.

Table A

```
t_item      t_cwar  t_koor  t_qstk
G00046301   EWH200  2   5000
G00046301   EWH200  2   5000
G00046301   EWH200  2   5000
G00046301   EWH200  2   5000
G00046301   EWH200  2   5000
G00046301   EWH200  22  5000
G00046301   EWH401  22  5000
G00046301   EWH401  1   72
G00053001   EWH200  2   5000
G00053001   EWH200  22  5000
G00053001   EWH200  2   5000
G00053001   EWH200  22  5000
G00053001   EWH401  22  5000
G00053001   EWH401  1   5
G00053001   EWH401  51  -4995
G00053001   EWH401  22  5000
G00053001   EWH401  1   50
G00251701   EWH200  2   900
G00251701   EWH200  22  900
G00251701   EWH200  2   900
G00251701   EWH200  2   900
G00251701   EWH200  2   900
G00251701   EWH200  2   900
G00251701   EWH200  22  900
```

Table B

```
t_waid  t_dicl
EWH100  EV
EWH200  EV
EWH300  EV
EWH301  EV
EWH400  EV
EWH401  EV
EWH800  EV
EWH801  EV
```

Table C

```
t_item  t_cwar  t_qhnd
G00046301   EWH200  20000
G00046301   EWH401  4928
G00053001   EWH401  4950
G00053001   EWH200  0
G00245101   EWH200  0
G00245101   EWH401  0
G00245101   EWH301  0
```

Query is

```
select
    Table_B.t_dicl as Department,
    Table_A.t_item as Item,
    sum(Table_B.t_qstk) as "Production Order" 
from
    Table_A,
    Table_B 
where
    Table_A.t_waid = Table_B.t_cwar
    and
    Table_A.t_koor = 1
```

Above query to obtain this data

```
Department       Item       Production Order
EV           G00046301      72
EV           G00053001      55
EV           G00251701      220
EV           G00386201      244
EV           G01021001      55
EV           G01037101      355
EV           G02280100      6
EV           G02280200      55
```

Next query

```
select
    Table_B.t_dicl as Department,
    Table_C.t_item as Item,
    sum( Table_C.t_qhnd ) as Quantity 
from
    Table_C, 
    Table_B
where
    Table_B.t_waid = Table_C.t_cwar
group by
    Table_C.t_item,
    Table_B.t_dicl
```

Above Query

```
Department      Item        Quantity
EV              123         0
EV              A1234       0
EV              G00046301   24928
EV              G00053001   4950
EV              G00245101   0
EV              G00251701   3400
EV              G00386201   11776
EV              G01021001   650
EV              G01030801   2000
EV              G01037101   5650
```

so i try to combine both query to obtain single table by using inner join

```
select
    Table_B.t_dicl as Department,
    Table_A.t_item as Item,
    sum( Table_A.t_qstk )  as "Production Order" , 
    sum(Table_C.t_qhnd) as Quantity
from
(
    (
        Table_A 
        inner join Table_C on
            Table_A.t_item = Table_C.t_item
    )
    inner join Table_B on Table_B.t_waid =Table_A.t_cwar
)
where
    Table_A.t_koor = 1
group by
    Table_A.t_item,
    Table_B.t_dicl


Department    Item      Production Order    Quantity on Hand
EV           G00046301  144                 24928
EV           G00053001  110                 9900
EV           G00251701  440                 6800
EV           G00386201  976                 35328
EV           G01021001  110                 1300
EV           G01037101  710                 28250
EV           G02280100  12                  1994
EV           G02280200  110                 23900
EV           G03536100  15                  700
EV           G04655100  710                 16950
EV           G05009800  426                 8376
```

Sample Expected output

```
Department  Item    Production Order    Quantity
EV           G00046301      72  24928
EV           G00053001  55      4950
EV           G00251701  220     3400
EV           G00386201  244     11776
EV           G01021001  55      650
EV           G01037101  355     5650
EV           G02280100  6       1994
EV           G02280200  55      11950
EV           G03536100  5       700
EV           G04655100  355     5650
```

some of the value is not tele and multiplied. Thanks in advance, im just trying to learn SQL here

Comment: Have you heard of `join`?  Of table aliases?  Your queries are really hard to read.

Comment: I have fix it, hope it will help. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ab.*, cb.*
FROM(
    select
        b.t_dicl as Department,
        a.t_item as Item,
        sum(b.t_qstk) as "Production Order" 
    FROM Table_A   AS a INNER JOIN Table_B  AS b ON a.t_waid  = b.t_cwar
    WHERE a.t_koor = 1
    GROUP BY b.t_dicl, a.t_item
    )As ab FULL OUTER JOIN(

        select
        b.t_dicl as Department,
        c.t_item as Item,
        sum( c.t_qhnd ) as Quantity 
    from
        Table_C AS c INNER JOIN Table_B AS B ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar

    group by
        c.t_item,
        b.t_dicl
    )AS cb  ON  ab.Department = cb.Department  AND ab.Item = cb.Item
```

Comment: Thank you, your query help me solve this problem. :*